# Resizing Image object

Tags: java, image, awt, image-scaling

I create Image and Graphics2D objects:

```
        image = createImage(width, height);
        buffer = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
```

Then why this code is not working:

```
image =image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
buffer = (Graphics2D)  image.getGraphics();
```

It throws:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getGraphics() not valid for images created with createImage(producer)
> at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage.getGraphics(ToolkitImage.java:310)

I'm not sure if I understand it, but it seems like Image object created with `createImage()`  method and Image object created with  `getScaledInstance()` are not equal. Is there any option to use `getScaledInstance()` to only resize `image` without changing other values inside object so I can call `getGraphics()` then?

Comment: Try creating  your image using a `BufferedImage`. If you still have problems post an [mre] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Another alternative is to do all your image processing on the original `BufferedImage` and save the scaling to an `Image` for the last step.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard method for converting an `Image` to a `BufferedImage`.

This method will do the conversion.  Feel free to choose a different `BufferedImage` type than `TYPE_INT_RGB`.

```
public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image) {
    if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
        return (BufferedImage) image;
    }

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    
    return bi;
}
```